# how to join the ABox for ontology with its corresponding owl

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

I got the owl for a books Ontology

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Prefixes
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

@prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> .
@prefix dcterms:     <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix foaf:        <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix gr:          <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#> .
@prefix owl:         <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix pto:         <http://www.productontology.org/id/> .
@prefix rdf:         <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix skos:        <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix xsd:         <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

@prefix opdm:    <http://purl.org/opdm/utility#> .
@prefix oggl:    <http://purl.org/opdm/category/google#> .

# Prefix of this vocabulary: obk
# - "o" as in the first letter of the project "OPDM"
# - "bk" as in the first two consonants of the main Product Type "Book" 
#   (criterion borrowed from UNIX commands).

@prefix obk:    <http://purl.org/opdm/book#> .

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Ontology
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

obk:
    a owl:Ontology ;
    owl:imports <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1> ,
                opdm: ;
    rdfs:label "Book Vocabulary"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "Vocabulary for describing books."@en ;
    dcterms:subject "book, audio book, ebook, reading"@en ;
    dcterms:creator "Bene Rodriguez-Castro" ,
                    "Laszlo Torok" ,
                    "Martin Hepp" ,
                    <http://www.unibw.de/ebusiness/> ,
                    <http://opdm-project.org/> ;
    .

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Classes
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Product Type Classes -------------------------------------------------------

obk:Book 
    a owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf gr:ProductOrService ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "Book"@en ;
    foaf:depiction <http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0a/Urval_av_de_bocker_som_har_vunnit_Nordiska_radets_litteraturpris_under_de_50_ar_som_priset_funnits_%283%29.jpg/220px-Urval_av_de_bocker_som_har_vunnit_Nordiska_radets_litteraturpris_under_de_50_ar_som_priset_funnits_%283%29.jpg> ;
    opdm:category oggl:Media_Books ;
    rdfs:comment "Super class of all books"@en .

# Utility Classes ------------------------------------------------------------

obk:BookFormat
    a owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf gr:QualitativeValue ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "BookFormat"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "Format of the book"@en .

obk:ElectronicFormat
    a owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf obk:BookFormat ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "ElectronicFormat"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "Electronic (not-printed) format"@en .

obk:PaperFormat
    a owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf obk:BookFormat ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "PaperFormat"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "Paper format"@en .

obk:Person
    a owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf gr:QualitativeValue ,
        foaf:Person ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "Person"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "Person associated to the book as an author, narrator (for an audio book) or any other function"@en .

# Look into canonical taxonomies of literary genres.
# There is always Wikipedia/DBpedia.
# From Wikipedia Book entry infobox: Epic, Lyric, Drama, Romance, 
#                                    Satire, Tragedy, Comedy, Tragicomedy
obk:BookGenre
    a owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf gr:QualitativeValue ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "BookGenre"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "Vocabulary of literary genres preferably derived from a established literary taxonomy of genres but at the same time open-ended."@en .

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Individuals
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# (obk:BookFormat) -----------------------------------------------------------

obk:Hardcover
    a obk:PaperFormat ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "Hardcover"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "The hardcover version of a book"@en .

obk:Paperback 
    a obk:PaperFormat ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "Paperback"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "The paperback format version of a book"@en .

obk:Audiobook 
    a obk:ElectronicFormat ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "Audiobook"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "The audio format version of a book"@en .

obk:Ebook 
    a obk:ElectronicFormat ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "Ebook"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "The electronic format version of a book"@en .

# (obk:BookGenre) ------------------------------------------------------------

obk:Epic
    a obk:BookGenre ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "Epic"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "The Epic literary genre"@en .

obk:Lyric
    a obk:BookGenre ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "Lyric"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "The Lyric literary genre"@en .

obk:Drama
    a obk:BookGenre ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "Drama"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "The Drama literary genre"@en .

obk:Fiction
    a obk:BookGenre ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "Fiction"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "The Fiction literary genre"@en .

# ... rest of genres

obk:GenreN
    a obk:BookGenre ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:label "Genre N"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "Not to be used. Genre N represents the notion of the open-ended type of genres that can be defined"@en .

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Datatype Properties
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# (gr:datatypeProductOrServiceProperty) --------------------------------------

obk:abstract
    a owl:DatatypeProperty ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf gr:datatypeProductOrServiceProperty ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:domain obk:Book ;
    rdfs:range xsd:string ;
    rdfs:label "Abstract"@en ;
    opdm:minCardinality "0"^^xsd:string;
    opdm:maxCardinality "1"^^xsd:string;
    rdfs:comment "Abstract of the book"@en ;
    opdm:isConfiguredBy [
        a opdm:MetadataContainer ;
        opdm:inProfile opdm:DefaultProfile ;
        opdm:attributePosition "0"^^xsd:integer ;
        opdm:exampleOfUsage "The value of this property is a textual description (xsd:string)."^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:rankingDirection "DESC"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:priority "0"^^xsd:integer ; 
    ] ;
    .

obk:numberOfPages
    a owl:DatatypeProperty ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf gr:datatypeProductOrServiceProperty ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:domain obk:Book ;
    rdfs:range xsd:integer ;
    rdfs:label "Number of pages"@en ;
    opdm:minCardinality "0"^^xsd:string;
    opdm:maxCardinality "1"^^xsd:string;
    rdfs:comment "The number of pages of the book. It applies only to books in paper and electronic-book format"@en ;
    opdm:isConfiguredBy [
        a opdm:MetadataContainer ;
        opdm:inProfile opdm:DefaultProfile ;
        opdm:attributePosition "0"^^xsd:integer ;
        opdm:exampleOfUsage "The value of this property is a numeric value (xsd:integer)."^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:rankingDirection "DESC"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:priority "0"^^xsd:integer ; 
    ] ;
    .

obk:publishedDate
    a owl:DatatypeProperty ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf gr:datatypeProductOrServiceProperty ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:domain obk:Book ;
    rdfs:range xsd:date ;
    rdfs:label "Published date"@en ;
    opdm:minCardinality "0"^^xsd:string;
    opdm:maxCardinality "*"^^xsd:string;
    rdfs:comment "The date(s) that the book has been published"@en ;
    opdm:isConfiguredBy [
        a opdm:MetadataContainer ;
        opdm:inProfile opdm:DefaultProfile ;
        opdm:attributePosition "0"^^xsd:integer ;
        opdm:exampleOfUsage "The value of this property is a valid date (xsd:date)."^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:rankingDirection "DESC"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:priority "0"^^xsd:integer ; 
    ] ;
    .

obk:publishedIn 
    a owl:DatatypeProperty ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf gr:datatypeProductOrServiceProperty ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:domain obk:Book ;
    rdfs:range xsd:language ;
    rdfs:label "Published in"@en ;
    opdm:minCardinality "0"^^xsd:string;
    opdm:maxCardinality "*"^^xsd:string;
    rdfs:comment "The language in which the book is published."@en ;
    opdm:isConfiguredBy [
        a opdm:MetadataContainer ;
        opdm:inProfile opdm:DefaultProfile ;
        opdm:attributePosition "0"^^xsd:integer ;
        opdm:exampleOfUsage "The value of this property is a valid xsd:language code (xsd:language). See description at <http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/PR-xmlschema11-2-20120119/datatypes.html#language>"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:rankingDirection "DESC"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:priority "0"^^xsd:integer ; 
    ] ;
    .

obk:title
    a owl:DatatypeProperty ;
    a owl:FunctionalProperty;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf gr:datatypeProductOrServiceProperty ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:domain obk:Book ;
    rdfs:range xsd:string ;
    rdfs:label "Title"@en ;
    opdm:minCardinality "0"^^xsd:string;
    opdm:maxCardinality "1"^^xsd:string;
    rdfs:comment "Title of the book"@en ;
    opdm:isConfiguredBy [
        a opdm:MetadataContainer ;
        opdm:inProfile opdm:DefaultProfile ;
        opdm:attributePosition "0"^^xsd:integer ;
        opdm:exampleOfUsage "The value of this property is a textual description (xsd:string)."^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:rankingDirection "DESC"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:priority "0"^^xsd:integer ; 
    ] ;
    .

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Object Properties
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# (gr:qualitativeProductOrServiceProperty) -----------------------------------

obk:author 
    a owl:ObjectProperty ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf gr:qualitativeProductOrServiceProperty ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:domain obk:Book ;
    rdfs:range obk:Person ;
    rdfs:label "Author"@en ;
    opdm:minCardinality "0"^^xsd:string;
    opdm:maxCardinality "1"^^xsd:string;
    rdfs:comment "The author of the book"@en ;
    opdm:isConfiguredBy [
        a opdm:MetadataContainer ;
        opdm:inProfile opdm:DefaultProfile ;
        opdm:attributePosition "0"^^xsd:integer ;
        opdm:exampleOfUsage "The value of this property is an individual of the class obk:Person"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:rankingDirection "DESC"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:priority "0"^^xsd:integer ; 
    ] ;
    .

obk:format
    a owl:ObjectProperty ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf gr:qualitativeProductOrServiceProperty ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:domain obk:Book ;
    rdfs:range obk:BookFormat ;
    rdfs:label "Format of the book"@en ;
    opdm:minCardinality "0"^^xsd:string;
    opdm:maxCardinality "n"^^xsd:string;
    rdfs:comment "Book format"@en ;
    opdm:isConfiguredBy [
        a opdm:MetadataContainer ;
        opdm:inProfile opdm:DefaultProfile ;
        opdm:attributePosition "0"^^xsd:integer ;
        opdm:exampleOfUsage "The value of this property is an individual of the class obk:BookFormat (i.e. obk:AudioBook, obk:Paperback, etc.);"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:rankingDirection "DESC"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:priority "0"^^xsd:integer ; 
    ] ;
    .

obk:genre 
    a owl:ObjectProperty ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf gr:qualitativeProductOrServiceProperty ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:domain obk:Book ;
    rdfs:range obk:BookGenre ;
    rdfs:label "Genre of the book"@en ;
    opdm:minCardinality "0"^^xsd:string;
    opdm:maxCardinality "1"^^xsd:string;
    rdfs:comment "The genre of a book."@en ;
    opdm:isConfiguredBy [
        a opdm:MetadataContainer ;
        opdm:inProfile opdm:DefaultProfile ;
        opdm:attributePosition "0"^^xsd:integer ;
        opdm:exampleOfUsage "The value of this property is an individual of the class obk:BookGenre (i.e. obk:Fiction, obk:Drama, etc.);"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:rankingDirection "DESC"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:priority "0"^^xsd:integer ; 
    ] ;
    .

obk:narrator
    a owl:ObjectProperty ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf gr:qualitativeProductOrServiceProperty ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:domain obk:Book ;
    rdfs:range obk:Person ;
    rdfs:label "Narrator of the book"@en ;
    opdm:minCardinality "0"^^xsd:string;
    opdm:maxCardinality "1"^^xsd:string;
    rdfs:comment "The narrator of a book in audio format"@en ;
    opdm:isConfiguredBy [
        a opdm:MetadataContainer ;
        opdm:inProfile opdm:DefaultProfile ;
        opdm:attributePosition "0"^^xsd:integer ;
        opdm:exampleOfUsage "The value of this property is an individual of the class obk:Person"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:rankingDirection "DESC"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:priority "0"^^xsd:integer ; 
    ] ;
    .

obk:publisher 
    a owl:ObjectProperty ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf gr:qualitativeProductOrServiceProperty ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:domain obk:Book ;
    rdfs:range gr:BusinessEntity ;
    rdfs:label "Publisher of the book"@en ;
    opdm:minCardinality "0"^^xsd:string;
    opdm:maxCardinality "1"^^xsd:string;
    rdfs:comment "The publisher of the book"@en ;
    opdm:isConfiguredBy [
        a opdm:MetadataContainer ;
        opdm:inProfile opdm:DefaultProfile ;
        opdm:attributePosition "0"^^xsd:integer ;
        opdm:exampleOfUsage "The value of this property is an individual of the class gr:BusinessEntity"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:rankingDirection "DESC"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:priority "0"^^xsd:integer ; 
    ] ;
    .

# (gr:quantitativeProductOrServiceProperty) ----------------------------------


obk:lengthOfAudio
    a owl:ObjectProperty ;
    rdfs:subPropertyOf gr:quantitativeProductOrServiceProperty ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy obk: ;
    rdfs:domain obk:Book ;
    rdfs:range gr:QuantitativeValue ;
    opdm:recommendedUnitOfMeasure "SEC"^^xsd:string ;
    opdm:recommendedRangeOfMeasure [
        a gr:QuantitativeValue ;
        gr:hasMinValue "1"^^xsd:integer ;
    ] ;
    rdfs:label "Length of audiobook"@en ;
    opdm:minCardinality "0"^^xsd:string;
    opdm:maxCardinality "1"^^xsd:string;
    rdfs:comment "The length in seconds of the audio narration of the book. It applies only to books in audio format. Note: UN/CEFACT code for second is SEC"@en ;
    opdm:isConfiguredBy [
        a opdm:MetadataContainer ;
        opdm:inProfile opdm:DefaultProfile ;
        opdm:attributePosition "0"^^xsd:integer ;
        opdm:exampleOfUsage "The value of this property is an individual of the class gr:QuantitativeValue"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:rankingDirection "DESC"^^xsd:string ;
        opdm:priority "0"^^xsd:integer ; 
    ] ;
    .

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Annotation Properties
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

dcterms:creator
    a owl:AnnotationProperty .

dcterms:contributor
    a owl:AnnotationProperty .

dcterms:subject
    a owl:AnnotationProperty .

foaf:depiction
    a owl:AnnotationProperty .

foaf:Person
    a owl:Class .

skos:altLabel
    a owl:AnnotationProperty .
```

and I got also some ABox instances **but with different IRI**

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Populating the Book Product Type Ontology
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Prefixes
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

@prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix gr:      <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix pto:     <http://www.productontology.org/id/> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix skos:    <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

@prefix opdm:    <http://purl.org/opdm/utility#> .
@prefix oggl:    <http://purl.org/opdm/category/google#> .

@prefix obk:     <http://purl.org/opdm/book#> .

# Prefix of this example: 

@prefix obkex:     <http://purl.org/opdm/book/example#> .

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example 1.
# Book: The Help
# Format: Paper
# Alternative Formats: E-book, Audiobook
# Source: http://www.amazon.com/Help-Movie-Tie--Kathryn-Stockett/dp/0425245136/ref=zg_bs_books_2 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Represent the Author
obkex:KathrynStockettPerson 
    a obk:Person ;
    foaf:name "Kathryn Stockett"@en ; 
    foaf:givenName "Kathryn"@en ;
    foaf:familyName "Stockett"@en ; 
    gr:name "Kathryn Stockett"@en ; 
    gr:description "The author Kathryn Stockett"@en .

# Represent the Publisher
obkex:BerkleyTradePublisher 
    a gr:BusinessEntity ;
    gr:legalName "Berkley Trade" ; 
    gr:name "Berkley Trade" ;
    gr:description "The publishing company Berkley Trade"@en .

# Represent the Book
obkex:TheHelpBook 
    a obk:Book ;
    opdm:category oggl:Media_Books ;
    gr:name "The Help Book"@en ;
    gr:description "The Help Book"@en ;
    obk:title "The Help"@en ;
    obk:author obkex:KathrynStockettPerson ;
    obk:format obk:Hardcover, 
               obk:Paperback, 
               obk:Audiobook, 
               obk:Ebook ;
    obk:genre obk:Drama,
              obk:Fiction ;
    obk:numberOfPages "544"^^xsd:integer ; 
    obk:publisher obkex:BerkleyTradePublisher ;
    obk:publishedDate "2011-06-28"^^xsd:date ; 
    obk:publishedIn "en"^^xsd:language ;
    gr:hasEAN_UCC-13 "9780425245132"^^xsd:string ;
    gr:weight [ 
        # representation of 9.6 ounces using UN/CEFACT
        a gr:QuantitativeValue ;
        gr:hasValue "9.6"^^xsd:float ; 
        gr:hasUnitOfMeasurement "ONZ"^^xsd:string 
    ] ;
    gr:height [ 
        # representation of 8.3 inches using UN/CEFACT
        a gr:QuantitativeValue ;
        gr:hasValue "8.3"^^xsd:float ; 
        gr:hasUnitOfMeasurement "INH"^^xsd:string 
    ] ;
    gr:width [ 
        # representation of 5 inches using UN/CEFACT
        a gr:QuantitativeValue ;
        gr:hasValue "5"^^xsd:float ; 
        gr:hasUnitOfMeasurement "INH"^^xsd:string 
    ] ;
    gr:depth [ 
        # representation of 0.8 inches using UN/CEFACT
        a gr:QuantitativeValue ;
        gr:hasValue "0.8"^^xsd:float ; 
        gr:hasUnitOfMeasurement "INH"^^xsd:string 
    ] .
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example 2.
# Book: The Shining
# Format: Paper
# Alternative Format: Ebook, Audiobook
# Source: http://search.barnesandnoble.com/Shining/Stephen-King/e/9780385121675
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Represent the Author
obkex:StephenKingPerson 
    a obk:Person ;
    foaf:name "Stephen King"@en ; 
    foaf:givenName "Stephen"@en ;
    foaf:familyName "King"@en ; 
    gr:name "Stephen King"@en ; 
    gr:description "The auhtor Stephen King"@en .

# Represent the Publisher
obkex:KnopfDoubledayPublishingGroup 
    a gr:BusinessEntity ;
    gr:legalName "Knopf Doubleday Publishing Group" ; 
    gr:name "Knopf Doubleday Publishing Group"@en ;
    gr:description "The Knopf Doubleday Publishing Group"@en .

# Represent the Book
obkex:TheShiningBook 
    a obk:Book ;
    opdm:category oggl:Book ;
    gr:name "The Shining"@en ;
    gr:description "The Shining Book"@en ;
    obk:title "The Shining"@en ;
    obk:author obkex:StephenKingPerson ;
    obk:format obk:Hardcover, 
               obk:Paperback, 
               obk:Audiobook, 
               obk:Ebook ;
    obk:genre obk:Drama,
                     obk:Fiction ;
    obk:numberOfPages "464"^^xsd:integer ; 
    obk:publisher obkex:KnopfDoubledayPublishingGroup ;
    obk:publishedDate "2005-08-12"^^xsd:date ; 
    obk:publishedIn "en"^^xsd:language ;
    gr:hasEAN_UCC-13 "9780385121675"^^xsd:string .
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example 3.
# Book: The Shining
# Format: Audiobook
# Alternative Format: Paper, Ebook
# Source: http://www.audible.com/pd/ref=sr_1_1?asin=B002VA8R8O&qid=1315475776&sr=1-1
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Represent the Author
obkex:StephenKingPerson 
    a obk:Person ;
    foaf:name "Stephen King"@en ; 
    foaf:givenName "Stephen"@en ;
    foaf:familyName "King"@en ;
    gr:name "Stephen King"@en ; 
    gr:description "The auhtor Stephen King"@en .

# Represent the Narrator
obkex:CampbellScott 
    a obk:Person ;
    foaf:name "Campbell Scott"@en ; 
    foaf:givenName "Campbell"@en ;
    foaf:familyName "Scott"@en ;
    gr:name "Campbell Scott"@en ;
    gr:description "The book narrator Campbell Scott"@en .

# Represent the Publisher
obkex:SimonAndSchusterAudio
    a gr:BusinessEntity ;
    gr:legalName "Simon & Schuster Audio"@en ;
    gr:name "Simon & Schuster Audio"@en ;
    gr:description "The audio book publishing company Simon & Schuster Audio"@en .

# Represent the Book
obkex:TheShiningAudioBook 
    a obk:Book ;
    opdm:category oggl:Book ;
    gr:name "The Shining"@en ;
    gr:description "The audio book The Shining"@en ;
    obk:title "The Shining"@en ;
    obk:author obkex:StephenKingPerson ;
    obk:narrator obkex:CampbellScott ;
    obk:format obk:Audiobook,
               obk:Paperback, 
               obk:Hardcover, 
               obk:Ebook ;
    obk:genre obk:Drama,
                     obk:Fiction ;
    obk:publisher obkex:SimonAndSchusterAudio ;
    obk:publishedDate "2005-08-12"^^xsd:date ; 
    obk:publishedIn "en"^^xsd:language ;
    obk:lengthOfAudio [
        # representation of 15 hours and 54 minutes in UN/CEFACT seconds
        a gr:QuantitativeValue ;
        gr:hasValue "57240"^^xsd:integer ;
        gr:hasUnitOfMeasurement "SEC"^^xsd:string
    ] .
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Untyped conceptual elements
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

foaf:Person
    a owl:Class ;
    .

foaf:depiction
    a owl:AnnotationProperty ;
    .

foaf:familyName
    a owl:AnnotationProperty ;
    .

foaf:givenName
    a owl:AnnotationProperty ;
    .

foaf:name
    a owl:AnnotationProperty ;
    .
```

Any idea please about how to join them, and by join them I mean allow protege to see them as if they were one owl (one ontology) that has instnaces for there classes.

I don't mind if the instances are from different IRI than the classes, I just would like to be able to see them together in protege.

I tried to import them together to protege, but protege didn't show the instances, i don't know why

#### update

this is the ontology that i get when importing both of them

```
@prefix : <http://www.BookSemanticOntology.com/bso#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.BookSemanticOntology.com/bso> .

<http://www.BookSemanticOntology.com/bso> rdf:type owl:Ontology ;

                                          owl:imports <file:/Users/ania/Downloads/laczoka-opdm_ontologies-410158ea3d5c/book_example.n3> ,
                                                      <http://purl.org/opdm/book#> .

###  Generated by the OWL API (version 4.1.3.20151118-2017) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi
```

#### Update2

As you see in the joined ontology (the first update), there is nothing about the books-example.n3 ontology. maybe because after importing the first ontology (books.n3), and then when i tried to import the second ontology (books-examples.n3), i got this :

[image]

so maybe the second one is not even imported.

#### Update3

I gave you the whole books.n3 and books-example.n3, so you can try it directly on protege if you wish and like, thanks in advance. Grazie

Comment: What do you "different IRI"? It looks like the obk (and other) prefixes are the same...

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I see the ABox instances from `<http://purl.org/opdm/book/example#>` while the classes from `<http://purl.org/opdm/book#> ` . It is fine for me as long as I can see both of them in my Protege

Comment: Ok, so what's the actual problem? Typically you'd just create a new ontology in protégé and then import both of these ontologies.  Is something not working about that?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor when I did that, I got just the classes, I couldn't see the ABox instances.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor there is a work arround, which is set this prefix `obkex` to this IRI `<http://purl.org/opdm/book/example#>` and then copy the ABox to the owl file. That works in such a small ontology. However, in a hug datasets, that is not possible

Comment: I wonder if there are any settings in protégé that hide individuals in imported ontologies or anything like that.  Is check to make sure that you're new ontology correctly imports the other two.  I know I've dive this in the past and have been able to see content from both.  You haven't shown us your new ontology, so we can't really help with it though.

Comment: Just as a comment, using your ontology does not really produce instance data despite class assertions, as you have in your ontology only properties of type `owl:AnnotationProperty`. From the FOAF specs, those should be mostly of type `http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#DatatypeProperty` instead.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor now I see the problem, i made two updates, could you check please?

Comment: @AKSW it is not me who developed it. I just want to import both of them in my protege

Comment: There is a bit of a problem in the abox file - no ontology declaration, so it is not an ontology. This will be included as plain RDF content in the importing ontology.  But, this seems to cause issues. I would work around the problem by adding an ontology header  to the abox file: `obkex:    a owl:Ontology ;`